# `Unexpected attribute declaration statement` in data statement

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I tried to write some data in Fortran:

```
   program Problem

    DIMENSION X(8), W(8)
    DATA X /0.0950125098D0, 0.2816035507D0, 0.4580167776D0, 0.6178762444D0
 +         , 0.7554044083D0, 0.8656312023D0, 0.9445750230D0, 0.9894009349D0/
    DATA W /0.1894506104D0, 0.1826034150D0, 0.1691565193D0, 0.1495959888D0
 +        , 0.1246289712D0, 0.0951585116D0, 0.0622535239D0, 0.0271524594D0/

    D = 0.D0
    DO NJ=1,8
      D = D + X(NJ) + W(NJ) 
    ENDDO

    write(*,*) D

   end
```

But I always get the following error message: `Unexpected attribute declaration statement at (1)`.

Does anybody know why?

Comment: Thank you for your answer....I made a  minimal example in my question above

Comment: I believe the error is due to the width of your lines. If you make your lines < 80 chars it will work better. I highly recommend using an editor that can highlight these kinds of errors.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon you mean <= 72 I assume (for fixed formatted code) in Fortran

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark looking at the raw code (in edit mode) it looks to  me that the start position is OK but that the line length is a problem.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. How can I change the width of the lines? I am also not sure if this solves the problem....When I change my code to DATA X /1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1/ I get the error message "data statement (1) has more values than variables"

Comment: One way to avoid problems with `data` statements is to avoid `data` statements; since the Fortran 90 standard was published there have been better ways to do what `data` statements do.  While they haven't quite been declared obsolescent in the latest standard they are heading that way and it's difficult to think of a reason why any code one writes today should use them.  I could make similar comments about fixed-form source too.

Comment: Note that in fixed-form, line are 72 characters long **and** the first 5 characters must be either blank or contain a numeric label **and** column 6 is reserved for continuation line. That is, the "real" code must start at column 7. Your program violates all these rules. Note also that since you declare no variable, X, W and D are real, but you initialize with double precision numbers. If you really insist in writing Fortran 77, I suggest you first learn Fortran 77. An excellent resource is this book by Clive Page: http://www.star.le.ac.uk/~cgp/prof77.pdf Or better, learn Fortran 90.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I do not believe that one should still learn Fortran77. Furthermore, Fortran77 is not really the right nomenclature anymore. You can speak of Free Format code and Fixed Format code unless you really program according to the Fortran77 Standard and compile it with strict standard options. gfortran, on the other hand, does not allow to set the compilation options to compile with a strict f77 standard. Neither does the Intel compiler. PGI, then again, provides an ANSI compiler. So in short, learn F2018. Don't stick to the past! Look into the Future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already stated by others you should use the new fortran standard.  If you do that you can just remove the "+" you used to indicate a continuation line (should have been in column 6) and instead add an ampersand "&" at the end of the line that should be continued.
Then the program compiles and runs.  But as X and W are single precision you use too many digits in your data statement.  Use implicit none and declare all variables.  And get a textbook.

Answer (score 0):

Below you find a minor update to your code which allows it to compile:

```
      program Problemless

      dimension X(8), W(8)
      data X /0.0950125098D0, 0.2816035507D0, 0.4580167776D0,
     +        0.6178762444D0, 0.7554044083D0, 0.8656312023D0,
     +        0.9445750230D0, 0.9894009349D0/
      data W /0.1894506104D0, 0.1826034150D0, 0.1691565193D0,
     +        0.1495959888D0, 0.1246289712D0, 0.0951585116D0,
     +        0.0622535239D0, 0.0271524594D0/

      D = 0.D0
      do NJ=1,8
         D = D + X(NJ) + W(NJ) 
      enddo

      write(*,*) D

      end
```

Your code is written in Fixed-source form (See Section 6.3.3 of the [Fortran standard](https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/18/18-007r1.pdf)). This implies that you cannot have anything beyond column 72. All I've done is to correct this in the above.

If you are learning fortran, I would suggest to stop using the fixed format and start using the free format.

*no upvotes required for this post*